# How is questions per day calculated?

Tags: discussion

I was just looking at the Stack Exchange website and noticed that Server Fault is down to just <s>108 102 99 98 97 96 91 89 88 91</s> 70 [questions](http://stackexchange.com/sites#users) per day. This has dropped from [130 in Aug 2012](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/3601/9517) and I have a vague recollection of it being over 140 at one time.

How is the displayed questions per day calculated ?

Comment: It's clearly not "good questions per day" or it would be single digits.

Comment: If you mouse hover over the stat it says: `102 questions per day on average over the last 2 weeks` - I'd presume that to include weekends as well.  Not sure of the exact calculation though.

Comment: @TheCleaner: yah, it's more the mechanics I'm interested in

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I asked our Devs, and Kevin Montrose Responded with:

```
(# of new questions over last 14 days) / 14
```

There might be a little cache delay, but that is roughly it. Questions doesn't count deleted questions, but it does count closed questions.

Comment: Cheers Kyle. What constitutes a new question - does it take migrations in/out deletions etc into account ?